# Why do I get an `Inconsistent accessibility` issue when using ReactiveContentPage?

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I am trying to follow the [ReactiveUI.Cinephile](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/master/samples/xamarin-forms/Cinephile) sample using the `ContentPageBase`. But when I extend it on my View, I get this error:

`Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'ContentPageBase<HomeViewModel>' is less accessible than class 'HomeView'`

Here uis the `HomeView`:

```
namespace ReactiveTest.Views
{
    public partial class HomeView : ContentPageBase<HomeViewModel>
    {
        public HomeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `ContentPageBase` class

```
namespace ReactiveTest.Views
{
   public class ContentPageBase<TViewModel> : ReactiveContentPage<TViewModel> where TViewModel : class
   {
   }
}
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: we can't help you if you don't post the relevant code.  What does the class declaration for HomeView look like?

Comment: Sorry for that, I have added the relevant code

Comment: Is HomeViewModel public?

Comment: Wow, that's all it took. Thank you! I must have thought that the generic types doesn't have any effect on the base type. You can post an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure both HomeView AND HomeViewModel are public. The generic type effects accessibility too.